# SpatiaLite missing on DB Manager tree panel

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I am working with QGIS. I have created a new database in SpatiaLite and need to add some shape files and other files to it.

My problem is : I don't see SpatiaLite in DB Manager?

I only have PostGIS and Virtual Layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have added the Spatialite Database to your QGIS browser tree first.

Right-click the Spatialite connection > New Connection > Browse to the database you've already created.

It should now show up in DB Manager